# use Flex ItemRenderer in mx.controls.TextArea

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I want to integrate itemrenderers in a TextArea. The purpose is to visualize keywords with their own easy interface while the user still can treat the whole thing as normal text to select the font, fontsize, etc.

E.g. this could be the htmltext of the TextArea:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2">
    <P ALIGN="RIGHT">
      <FONT FACE="Century Gothic" SIZE="24" COLOR="#999999">
        The temperature is {TEMP|DEGREES}°.
      </FONT>
    </P>
</TEXTFORMAT>
```

In this example the part {TEMP|DEGREES} should be replaced with an ItemRenderer which shows a dropdown list with possible keywords (Temperature, Time, ...) and a second dropdown with parameters depending on the selected keyword (for Temperature that would be Degrees, Fahrenheit).

Any ideas or suggestions on how to handle this?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Comment: If you want to do this with mx TextArea, you'll be in a world of pain. It would be a lot easier with Spark TextArea. Is that an option?

Comment: I think even w/ the Spark TextArea this is going to be tough.  It sounds to me like you don't actually want a TextArea; but some custom coponent that is a mish-mash of multiple controls, created dynamically.

Comment: no, project is still in Flex3, so no Spark ...

Comment: sounds like the mish-mash solution would also be a world of pain ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, definitely not possible without *majorly* hacking TextArea, which in the end wouldn't really be a TextArea anymore.

I have done something similar to this however.  It was simple enough, just create a simple yet robust data structure (like say an array that contains custom models that has some sort of agnostic data property and a 'type' so you know what to do with it), iterate through then add it to a container (like HBox).  Depending on the type of data, you'll need some sort of algorithm that knows what to do with it (which 'item renderer' to create).

This is definitely possible as I've create a way to have dynamic complex forms based on data alone, but it's not the simplest thing to do.  You need to test it quite a bit and think about the data structure and how to abstract it quite a bit.  I would share the code with you, but the IP isn't mine.

Comment: that's probably indeed the best way to do. But the problem with this approach is, that you can not select the text across different renderers as you can do in the textarea. I need this functionality so the user can easily apply font, text size, etc.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well, this 'solution' is really just for displaying the end result.  If you need the user to modify the result or the text, you should try to use a full text driven approach with a proper user interface (like how stackoverflow does it).  For instance, everything is just text, and if they want a combobox, just have a button at the top of the text area that inserts `{ComboBox[value1, value2]}` or something else similar to that.  You'll then need to parse the text and create a proper data model for displaying.